# In Remote Desktop Service, remote app is not accessing through safari browser

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I have installed Remote Desktop Service using remote web app, with RDgateway server, RDSession host server, and all RD servers.

When we access the web application through rdp, it is accessing sucessfully through chrome, but it is not accessing through safari browser.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What version of RDS? (What version of Windows)

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2016 (Datacenter)....It is most urgetn for me to resolve the issue. please help me

Comment: The web access uses ActiveX and some HTML5 Components which are generally unsupported by older versions of safari. Either use another browser or install the MS Remote Desktop app to access desktops and hosted applications